# What's wrong with calling Objective-C __attribute__((overloadable)) functions from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop

I have two functions in Objective-C code declared with `__attribute__((overloadable))` attribute. I could normally call these functions from Objective-C code. I have not overloaded functions in same Objective-C file which I could normally call from both Objective-C and Swift. But when I call these overloaded functions from Swift, I can't even build project getting linker error:

[image]

Xcode 6.4.

What's wrong with calling overloaded Objective-C functions from Swift? Bug? Should I file radar?

Comment: Only a guessing: C function overloading support of clang is related to C++. Swift does not have an idea of C++.

Comment: `__attribute__` is compiler directive not related to any specific language from C/C++/Objective-C family.

Comment: In C++ you already have overloadable functions supported by the language itself. Therefore the attribute is meaningless. The attribute adds non-standard support for C++ overloadable functions to C. "Clang provides support for C++ function overloading in C." So Objective-C inherits overloadable functions from non-standard C, which inherits overloadable functions from C++.